# PHP: Create XML file and send it with curl?

Tags: php, xml, curl

How do I create an XML-file with PHP and then send it with curl?

I have come this far:

```
<?php 
ob_start();

header("Content-type: text/xml");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="feed.xml"');
?>

<products>
<?php
foreach ($products as $product)
{
?>
<product></product>
<?php    
}
?>
</products>

<?php
ob_flush();

 $curlOpts = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://website.com/api/importfile',
    CURLOPT_GET => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Authorization: api 1234-56789', 'Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="feed"; filename="feed.xml"')
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOpts);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

But don't know how to continue. How do I get it to be a "file" and connect it to the curl call? Do I have to save it as a file locally first? Or is it possible to just save it to the curl call?

Comment: you mean `upload` it or send it as a post parameters?

Comment: The API documentation says `In order to upload excel or xml file you perform a POST call to the importfile API with the file you wish to import.` and then `This request returns an http status code, indicating how the call went, including the ID of the uploaded file.` And then `The ImportId is used when calling the PUT importfile API.`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just need to send file using curl ... this might help:

http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/sending-files-using-curl/

Comment: Okay so I need to first save the file locally?